# Cannot run my app on iPhone because it's not paired with a watch?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I updated one of my apps to also run a little code on Apple Watch. I do not own an Apple Watch. After taking the time to do this, I found that Xcode refused to run my app on my phone, because the phone is not paired with an Apple Watch. Is it supposed to work that way? What about all of the customers who do not yet own an Apple Watch? Can they not use the app any longer?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious it is. Because if you don't have an iWatch, you have to run your app on simulator only. To get iWatch simulator, click on **iOS simulator -> Hardware -> External Displays, and then select Apple Watch-32mm OR Apple Watch-42mm**. Firstly run your app on iPhone simulator then run iWatch app, that automatically will run on iWatch simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change your iphone app and run it without watch.

Click the button (it will open like drop down) of on your xcode near app run and stop buttons, just select your iphone app (its name without watchkit) and run it. It will show you just phones in selectable devices for emulators.

Other one (watchkit) show you phones + watch like "iphone 7 + Apple Watch Series 38 mm". If you select watchkit and run it. It will expect apple watch.